# ActionMailer how to change layout in method in rails 2.3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-2

I'm trying to change the layout for a class using `ActionMailer::Base` on rails 2.3

```
layout 'email'

def my_mail(email)
  recipients email
  subject 'test'
  @body = Premailer.new(
    render_message(
      "view_name"
    ),
    :with_html_string => true,
  ).to_inline_css
end
```

I want to use another layout only for that method, I have tried with

```
layout 'email' # also :except => 'my_email'
layout 'other_layout', :only => 'my_email'
```

with no luck

Answer (score 0):

The best way I found to do this is:

```
layout :choose_layout

def choose_layout
  @layout ? @layout : 'email';
end

def my_mail(email)
   @layout = 'alternate_layout'
   ...
end
```